# VI editor _ move folder from Windows to Web server

Tags: php, windows, linux, ubuntu

I have a library ( folder) in my windows machine. I haven't worked with VI .

Comment: Why do you want to use a text editor to move a directory?

Answer (score 1):

why does VI (a text editor) come into this?

Moving folders from your local machine to your web server is normally done with FTP or HTTP not a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with FTP? Is your web server locally hosted? You do not need VI to transfer or upload files.